# Can you mention that you were a paper reviewer after it has been published?

Tags: peer-review, etiquette

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are the referees of a journal allowed to reveal the title of the papers they review after the review process?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3591/are-the-referees-of-a-journal-allowed-to-reveal-the-title-of-the-papers-they-rev)

Suppose you were a single-blind paper reviewer (i.e. you could see the author's name, but they couldn't see your name) and you didn't obviously de-anonymize yourself during the review. If the paper gets accepted and published, and you are writing a review/summary of it (in its published form, not in any pre-publication form you have seen) on your blog after it appears in print.

1. **Can you mention the fact that you were a reviewer for this paper?**
2. **Can you make comments about pre-publication versions of the paper?** For instance: 'when submitted the paper lacked X, but other reviewers and I suggested it to be added and after revisions the author provided a full proof of X'.

Comment: Why would you want to do 1?

Comment: @DanielE.Shub mostly to make the blog post more personal and convey the people side of research. I usually like to say how I came across a paper and usually it is through an author I follow or forward/backward-citations of things I've read. In this case however, I would never (or at least not so soon) have come across this paper if I was not a reviewer for it. Thanks for that second link! I knew I have seen something similar around, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Why don't you ask "that" (how to convey the people side of research).

Comment: @DanielE.Shub I don't know how to formulate that question in any non-vague way. Also, you guys are fast to spot and close dupes, I was hoping to vote to close my own question :D. Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: I'd say it strongly depends on the policy of a particular journal the paper is reviewed for, so you'd better check the guidelines for reviewers. If I recall correctly, there is at least one journal having the policy that the reviewer can disclose her/his identity to the author only if the paper was eventually published in the journal in question and only after the publication has actually taken place.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd just pretend that you stumbled across a paper, rather than say you reviewed it on your blog.

And you should **not** make comments about the pre-published version of the paper. This could be embarrassing for the author, and seriously violates the trust embodied in the reviewing process.